# Tense agreement: "Before he 'had come'/'came' to the factory, Tom 'was studying'/'had studied' at the university of London"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> 1. Before he **had come** to the factory, Tom **was studying** at the university
>      of London.
> 2. Before he **came** to the factory, Tom **had studied** at the University of
>      London.

Answer (score 5):

**K**eep **I**t **S**imple - **St**ick to [simple past](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepast.html).

> A: *Before he **came** to the factory, Tom **studied** at the University of London.*

Using [past perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html) *(had come)* places the narrative focus *further back in time*. Once you've started with that, you can't refer to anything *earlier* without also using past perfect, so OP's #1 is incorrect.

In this case, since *studying* predates *coming to the factory*, you could reasonably refer to the earlier action with past tense:

> B: *Before he **came** to the factory, Tom **had studied** at the university of London.*

It would be (just about) possible to use *had come* in B. But it serves no purpose unless the narrative context primarily concerns other events in the past which are all *later* than both *studying* and *coming to the factory*. That's a complex literary context which probably isn't relevant here, so just forget about it.

If OP wants to use [past continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html) for the *studying* (I see no good reason for that here, and it seems "stilted" at best), I might prefer to see that same verb form reflected in the initial clause:

> C: *Before **coming** to the factory, Tom **was studying** at the university of London.*

Note that A, B would be just as good with the "progressive/continuous" participle *(coming)*, and C would be just as bad with simple past *(he came)*. Although I must admit, "bad" is perhaps putting it too strongly; there are contexts where competent writers would use #3, but I don't think learners need concern themselves with this form until they've mastered the "standard" usages.

Answer (score 0):

> Before he came to the factory, Tom had studied at the University of London.

This is correct. The following structure is followed for this:

> Begin + Simple Past Tense, Past Perfect Tense.